# Trying to append all text that's two lines after a common string into a list

Tags: python, loops, with-statement

I am working with a large .txt file, and I'm trying to append all of the lines with geographic information into a list using Python. the data (which is 100s of lines long) looks like this:

```
Sourced
HR Leave Systems Project Coordinator at Hobby Lobby
Oklahoma City, Oklahoma, United States
Retail
ExperienceProfile experience
```

The data that I want to append into the list always comes two lines AFTER a line that says "sourced" ... I've tried the below code, but it appends in all of the lines that come right after the lines that say "sourced" (as opposed to two lines after):

```
with open(filename,"r") as fi:
        Geography =[]
        for line in fi:
            if line.startswith("Sourced"):
                Geography.append((next(fi, '').strip()))
```

Is there anything I can tweak here to get this working?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a state machine?

Comment: "but it appends in all of the lines that come right after the lines that say "sourced" (as opposed to two lines after)" Well, in your own words, why do you think it does that? How do you think the trick with `next` works?

Comment: To be clear: do you want both of the next two lines? Or only the one that's two after?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that, for your given input, your output should look like the following:

```
Geography = ["Oklahoma City, Oklahoma, United States"]
```

If that is the case, you can modify your code to look like this

```
with open(filename,"r") as fi:
    Geography =[]
    lines_since_last_sourced = 0
    for line in fi:
        if line.startswith("Sourced"):
            lines_since_last_sourced = 0
        else:
            lines_since_last_sourced += 1
            if lines_since_last_sourced == 2:
                Geography.append(line.strip())
```

Comment: This is a great approach, but it would help to talk a little bit more about the underlying logic.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything I can tweak here to get this working?

Well, `Geography.append((next(fi, '').strip()))` gives you one of the next lines, by *reading another line from the file*, processing it and appending it. You want that to happen to the next two lines, so all you would have to do in your approach is do that twice:

```
with open(filename, "r") as fi:
    Geography = []
    for line in fi:
        if line.startswith("Sourced"):
            Geography.append((next(fi, '').strip()))
            Geography.append((next(fi, '').strip())) # did I stutter?
```

However, for more complex logic like this I generally prefer to build a simple sort of state machine. In this case our "state" is just the number of lines we need to append to the list, starting with the current one. So, normally the value is 0, and we bump it up to 2 when we see the trigger line:

```
with open(filename, "r") as fi:
    Geography = []
    lines_to_add = 0
    for line in fi:
        if line.startswith("Sourced"):
            lines_to_add = 2 # remember that we need the next two
        elif lines_to_add > 0:
            lines_to_add -= 1 # we're adding this one, so count it
            Geography.append(line.strip())
```

This avoids messing with the iterator, so it's easier to understand - and also more easily modified in case you have more complex rules later.

We can go one step further: generally I recommend separating the process of building the list from the process of interpreting the file contents. That way we're *really* applying "functions should do one thing". A lot of languages don't offer any especially nice ways to do that, but in Python it's easy using generators:

```
def lines_from(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as fi:
        lines_to_add = 0
        for line in fi:
            if line.startswith("Sourced"):
                lines_to_add = 2
            elif lines_to_add > 0:
                lines_to_add -= 1
            yield line.strip() # this gives us a processed line element...

# ... which we can collect like so:
Geography = list(lines_from(filename))
```